# Excel vba How best to determine if .usedrange is empty

Tags: vba, excel

is there a quick way to determine, if `.usedrange` does actually return something?

A short example:

```
Dim wsKtE as worksheet
Dim KtE() As Variant

set wsKtE = ActiveSheet    
KtE = wsKtE.UsedRange
```

if there is no data in wsKtE I get a type does not match exception. I found, that I could that if both `wsKtE.usedrange.columns.count` and `wsKtE.usedrange.rows.count` are 1, than I can infer that the area is probably empty.

Is there a better way?

Thx Kaz

Comment: What you should do depends on why you want `UsedRange` and not something else. `UsedRange` can be a single cell or a range of cells, and it is populated depending on cell *usage*, not depending on whether they contain values (e.g. if you color some cells on an empty sheet they will go into `UsedRange` even though there is no data on the sheet).

Comment: E.g. it might be enough for you to test `IsEmpty(wsKtE.UsedRange.Value)` (because your code tries to assign `UsedRange.Value` to an array, which will fail when `.Value` is `Empty`), but then there will remain a case of a single-cell `UsedRange` where the `Value` will not be compatible with an array anyway, which you could detect that with `IsArray()` and construct the array manually. But it would seem to me you simply want to remove the `()` after `KtE()` so that whatever `Value` has to offer could be successfully assigned to it, and then potentially test `KtE` for `IsEmpty` and `IsArray`.

Comment: I know, that if the area is used, it is populated with values. I don't know how many or where. If I use `IsEmpty(wsKtE.UsedRange.Value)` it gives me `FALSE` with an empty sheet. Ah, but after removing the braces `IsEmpty(KtE)` does give me `TRUE`.

Comment: Because, as I said, empty sheet and unused sheet are different things. You need to decide what and why you need from the sheet and whether what you need is indeed `UsedRange`. If you are sure it is and `IsEmpty` is false, also check `IsArray`.

Answer (score 4):

```
? typename(activesheet.usedrange.value)

No content on sheet >> 'Empty'
One cell with content >> 'String','Double', etc
Multiple cells with content >> 'Variant()'
```