# Why would an Excel Worksheet object that represents a spreadsheet filled with data have an empty UsedRange field?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

The purpose of the following Excel VBA code is to copy into an array of Variant the value of every cell contained within the used region of the spreadsheet.

```
Public Function GetSingletonSpreadsheetArray(spreadsheetName As String) As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    If m_dictSpreadsheetArray Is Nothing Then
        Set m_dictSpreadsheetArray = New Dictionary
    End If
    
    If m_dictSpreadsheetArray.Exists(spreadsheetName) Then
        GetSingletonSpreadsheetArray = m_dictSpreadsheetArray(spreadsheetName)
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set ws = Worksheets(spreadsheetName)
    
    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    m_dictSpreadsheetArray.Add spreadsheetName, ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value
    
    Set ws = Nothing
    GetSingletonSpreadsheetArray = m_dictSpreadsheetArray(spreadsheetName)
End Function
```

The Excel VBA debugger never returns attempting to single step through this line (from the above code):

```
    lastCol = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Placing `ws` in Watch Window shows a *mostly* valid `Worksheet` object.  Conspicuously missing is the `UsedRange` value:

[image]

Why does this `Worksheet` object have no `UsedRange` value?  How do I get the last used row and column from this `Worksheet` object?  The corresponding spreadsheet definitely has data in it... about 5,000 rows using columns A through T.

Comment: `Set ws = Worksheets(spreadsheetName)` will this always be operating on the ActiveWorkbook?  There's no workbook qualifier on your call to `Worksheets()`  Likewise here `ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Value` will fail if `ws` is not the activesheet, since `Cells()` without a worksheet qualifier will default to `ActiveSheet.Cells()`

Comment: FYI how to determine is a sheet has an empty UsedRange: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39023422/478884